# How To get route matched template in .Net Core 2.2?

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

Having this attributes above my controller:

```
[Route("preflight/{textSlug}")]
[Route("magazine/{textSlug}")]
[Route("content/{textSlug}")]
```

How can I get the first part of the template(e.g: preflight)
without using:

```
var path = Request.Path.Value.ToLower();
if (path.Contains("preflight")
```

And not by Regex.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I was hoping there was other solution that doesn't involve Regex.

Comment: Instead of parsing `path` you are now parsing `route`? What's the difference? And why not by RegEx? It's a [valid alternative](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#regular-expressions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting current request route template, you could try `ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo.Template`.

```
[Route("preflight/{textSlug}")]
[Route("magazine/{textSlug}")]
[Route("content/{textSlug}")]
public IActionResult Privacy()
{ 
    var route = ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo.Template;
    return View();
}
```

Comment: This only works because the template starts with the action. But how are you going to determine the action in `[Route("[controller]/preflight/{textSlug}")]`? route.Contains("preflight")?

Answer (score 0):

How about giving `Route` a `Name`, e.g. `[Route("preflight/{textSlug}", Name="preflight")]`?

You can get which route the request is using by:

```cs
var name = ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo.Name;
```